# Winforms How to add my custom class as my own data type in setting file?

Tags: c#, winforms, setting

I have a simple class below and I like to add it as a data type in setting file as I can see it in the type list of setting designer:

```
namespace MyApp.Classes
{
    class BankCash
    {
        public string BankName { get; set; }
        public string BankNumber { get; set; }

        public BankCash(string bankName, string bankNumber)
        {
            BankName = bankName;
            BankNumber = bankNumber;
        }
    }
}
```

Any Idea? Thanks

Comment: I am unclear what you mean by setting designer. Are you referring to design time support for a winforms component?

Comment: Setting designer is same as grid view in user setting file.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I found in [this post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/482475/visual-studio-settings-page-browse-for-a-custom-type) it appears the class must be in a different assembly than the one you are creating the settings class for.

I also experimented with it a bit and it appears if you don't have a no-arg constructor the class won't show up either.

P.S. I'm assuming the constructor is a typo because the class is named `Bank` but the constructor is `BankCash`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, and sorry for my wrong type, so class name is BankCash